# Adjoints to $f^\ast: \mathscr P(L)\to \mathscr P(K)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, category-theory, order-theory, adjoint-functors

> An exercise from Leinster:
>
> [image]
>
> Here is my attempt. Let $\hat f:\mathscr P(K)\to\mathscr P(L)$ be the function given by $\hat f(T)=\{y\in L:y=f(x)\text{ for some }x\in T\}$. Note that $\hat f$ is order preserving. We find left and right adjoints below.

---

**(1.)** Let's find a right adjoint. This must be an order preserving function $G:\mathscr P(K)\to \mathscr P(L)$ such that $$\mathscr P(K)(f^\ast(l),k)\cong\mathscr P(L)(l,G(k)).$$

This means the following:

$$f^\ast(l)\subseteq k \text{ iff } l\subseteq G(k)$$

or

$$\{x\in K: f(x)\in l\}\subseteq k \text{ iff } l\subseteq G(k)$$

If $G=\hat f$, then the above holds.

---

**(2.)** Let's find a left adjoint. This is an order preserving function $F:\mathscr P(K)\to\mathscr P(L)$ such that

$$\mathscr P(L)(F(k),l)\cong \mathscr P(K)(k, f^\ast(l))$$ i.e.

$$F(k)\subseteq l\text{ iff } k\subseteq \{x\in K: f(x)\in l\}$$

And again we can take $F=\hat f$.

---

- Are the above arguments correct?
- Do I also need to verify the naturality conditions below in each case? I'm asking because they state that two arrows are equal, but in a poset category any two arrows between same objects are automatically equal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(2) holds: with $F=\hat f$, if $\hat f(k)\subseteq l$, then
$$k\ \subseteq\  f^{-1}(\hat f(k))\ \subseteq\ f^{-1}(l)$$
and conversely, if $k\subseteq f^{-1}(l)$, then $\hat f(k)\ \subseteq\ \hat f(f^{-1}(l))\ \subseteq\ l$.

For (1), however, you need another functor. Define
$$G(k):=\{y\in L: f^{-1}(y)\subseteq k\}$$
Note that if $f$ is not surjective, every $G(k)$ contains $L\setminus \hat f(K)$.
Note also that, we basically *changed the quantifier* inside the definition, so that now $y$ is required to satisfy that *all* of its preimages lie in $k$.
Try to prove the equivalences of the respective inclusions.

(3) For the naturality part, you're absolutely right: in a poset category every square commutes.

Comment: I don't quite see why $\bar f$ doesn't work for (1). Consider this picture: http://s1.bild.me/bilder/110417/2051648clipboard2.png Suppose $f^{-1}(l)\subset k$. This means that the green circle on the left lies inside the red circle. The image of the green circle is the light green circle, and the image of the red circle is the pink circle. Then $l\subset \hat f(k)$ because the light green circle lies inside the pink circle. And concersely, if the light green circle lies inside the pink one, then on the left the green circle must lie inside the red one.

Comment: Your picture is a bijection. Try a nonsurjective, noninjective map. Also note my notes in the answer.

Comment: Okay, so in my picture the image of the green circle may be a proper subset of the light green circle, and the pink circle may be contained inside the light green circle. I understood why your definition works, but I don't understand that you're saying that in this new definition we have change the quantifier. If we took my definition and changed the quantifier, wouldn't we obtain $G(T)=\{f(x):x\in T\}$? (And wouldn't it be the same set as $\hat f(T)$?) This is not the same as your definition.

Comment: (Not sure why, but someone down-voted the answer; I up-voted it.)

Comment: Work out an example for an $f$ with fibers of $0,1,2,3$ elements.

Comment: So, specifically, draw the sets for $f:\{a, b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2,c_3\}\to \{u, x, y, z\} $ mapping $a\mapsto x, \ b_i\mapsto y, \  c_j\mapsto z$.